# How can I expose an existing JetEngine map so that I can hook into it and add extra custom JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, maps, hook

I have the Crocoblock suite of plugins in WordPress, and I am using the JetEngine map functionality to create a map on which I am plotting points stored in custom posts.

JetEngine maps lack some Google/Leaflet map functionality, such as adding ploygons and overlays. I need to work with these and add some related features, such as being able to display a polygon that the user can switch on and off by clicking a button or flicking a switch.

I figure the best way to do it is to create my JetEngine map as normal, then inject some custom JavaScript code into the page footer or elsewhere to add the additional functionality I need.

However, my understanding is that the map object is not normally exposed (made public) in such a way that allows this.

I found another user talking about this issue, and they posted a bit of code that can apparently be patched into the JetEngine plugin to make the map object public. Link here:

https://github.com/Crocoblock/suggestions/issues/5738

I have patched this code into JetEngine but have not been able to successfully get any additional custom code to work.

My current method of injecting the custom JS is to use a header/footer code insertion plugin to add the code to the footer for that page.

I have tried using both a Google map and a Leaflet map but neither seem to work (I don't really mind which one I end up using).

An example of the type of code block I am injecting:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var latlang = [
    [[17.385044, 78.486671], [16.506174, 80.648015], [17.686816, 83.218482]],
    [[13.082680, 80.270718], [12.971599, 77.594563],[15.828126, 78.037279]]
  ];
  var multiPolyLineOptions = {color:'red'};
  var multipolyline = L.multiPolyline(latlang , multiPolyLineOptions);
  multipolyline.addTo(map);
});
```

Any suggestions for solutions along this line, or any other method of solving this problem, would be appreciated.